# 9Patch image not strectching

Tags: android

I am using http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html to create a 9Patch image which is attached. [image]. I use this is to set a drawableBottom to the TextView.But this does not stretch to the width the text view. What am i doing wrong ? This is the original image 
[image]

Comment: I don't know much about TextView's drawableBottom, but have you definitely named your resource "whatever.9.png"? Android takes the resource name as a hint that it should treat the PNG as a 9-patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few reasons for it to "not stretch"

Guides must only be one pixel wide, so if you want a 48×48 button, your png will actually be 50×50. Anything thicker than one pixel will remain part of your image.

guides must be solid black (#000000). Even a slight difference in color (#000001) or alpha will cause it to fail

MOST IMPORTANT: you should keep in mind that remaining area of the one-pixel outline must be completely transparent. This includes the four corners of the image – those should always be clear. This can be a bigger problem than you realize. For example, if you scale an image in Photoshop it will add anti-aliased pixels which may include almost-invisible pixels which will also cause it to fail*. If you must scale in Photoshop, use the Nearest Neighbor setting in the Resample Image pulldown menu (at the bottom of the Image Size pop-up menu) to keep sharp edges on your guides.

http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Comment: If i send you this image, could you create a 9Patch for me please ?

Comment: Thank you. Sent. Appreciare your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use android sdk draw9patch tool to make a 9-patch image.

you will need to define stretchable patches to image border like shown in below image border.

[image: 9-patch image]

Comment: The Android Asset Studio should be a perfectly fine way of generating 9-patch images, and you can see the stretchable patches defined in the image in the question...